# How to handle changing between different types of black ink? (Epson Stylus Photo R2880)

Tags: printer, ink-jet

I have an Epson Stylus Photo R2880. This printer has two types of black ink. One for glossy papers, and one for matte papers.

There is not room for both in the printer - they both share the same slot - so I have to remove the one, if I need to use the other. So far I have not used the matte black yet, but I guess I should if I would like printing on matte papers to be at its best quality.

But that leads to the question which I can't seem to see being addressed in the manual. How to handle the ink that is not currently on the printer. I would need to remove the glossy black ink. How should I store it? Wouldn't it dry out? Can ink leak from the cartridge?

Answer (score 1):

I use the same printer and have the same problem. As an Epson fanatic I only use epson original cartridges. 
The way I store the resting cartridge is to place it in one of the plastic sheaths that come with a new cartridge. The ink seems to last ok without too much drying outand so far there has been no spillage.
The only downside is that you have to put the resting cartridge in a safe place.
hope this helps